# Rows not showing up in DataTable

Tags: datatables

I have a DataTable in my view like this:

```
 <table id="tblProviders" style="font-size:x-small;width:100%; border: 1px solid black;">
                <caption>Assigned Providers</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Remove</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

And the assignment of the data:

```
 $("#tblProviders").dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetProvidersById")?id=' + $("#txtid").val(),
        bJQueryUI: true,
        sProcessing: "<img src='~/Images/spinner.gif' />",
        dom: 'T<"clear">rtip',
        "pageLength": 5,
        bAutoWidth: false,
        "oLanguage": {
            sEmptyTable: "There are no Providers at this time",
            sZeroRecords: "There are no Providers at this time"
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "1%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "smallfonts" },
            {
                "sWidth": "15%", sClass: "centerbutton", "sName": "UserId", "mRender": function (data, type, row) {

                    return "<button type='button' class='displaybutton' id='" + row[0] + "' onclick=RemoveProvider(this);return false; >Remove</button>";
                }
            }
        ],
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "../../Scripts/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [

            ]

        }
    });
    $("#tblProviders").dataTable().fnSetColumnVis(0, false);
    otab = $("#tblProviders").dataTable();
    otab.fnSort([[1, 'asc']]);
```

I know I am getting the correct JSON data with this:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetProvidersId(string id)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            aaData = Repository.GetProvidersById(id).Select(x => new String[] {
                x.ID.ToString(),
                x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
                x.Email,
                x.Phone,
                x.Role,
            })
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But yet none of the rows shows up.  What am I doing wrong here?  In fact, if I debug on the loading of the table by putting a debug point at the Remove spot, I see the data but it never displays.

Comment: What version of DataTables are you using?

Comment: @thirtydot I am using 1.10.10

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle which should help: https://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/oec7rnd7/ (I'm using special tactics for jsFiddle to simulate a JSON response). `mData` is important, at least for the data format I chose. Also, you should switch to the new API, it's less confusing. I will update my answer to make sense when I can.

Comment: And here's an example without using `mData`, using the same data format I believe you are using: https://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/oec7rnd7/1/. I think your problem is that you aren't wrapping your data like this: `{"data": [["id 1", "name 1", "email 1", "phone 1", "role 1"], ["id 2", "name 2", "email 2", "phone 2", "role 2"]]}`. If it's not that, I think it's something I can't see from the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the problem was caused by the use of the alphabet search I loaded into the main view.  Once the filtering started and a partial view displayed, the filtering continued in that partial view, effectively showing no results.  I have another question regarding that problem with no answer as yet.